# Calling Javascript function from within a DataGrid

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, datagrid

I have a data grid, which contains a call to a javascript function as follows.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="panel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<DataGrid id="dg" runat="server">
<Columns>
<TemplateColumns>
<ItemTemplate>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<script type="text/javascript">doStuff('<%# Container.ItemIndex %>', '<%# Eval("Count")%>');</script>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</ItemTemplate>
</TemplateColumns>
</Columns>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doStuff(A, B){...};
</script>
```

It was working previously without the update panel. After the datagrid is included within the update panel, the javascript is not being called. I have looked at various solutions but none of them worked. Can anyone suggest how to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Check the generated code what is the difference between this and old version?

Comment: It seems like this is due to the partial postback, the javascript function is not getting bound again. It works only the first time when the page loads. Following is one of the solutions I found but not sure how I can pass the arguments 
[link](http://www.codepal.co.uk/show/JQuery_breaks_after_ASPNET_partial_page_postback)

Comment: I'm surprised it works at all.  Your function doesn't have a name and your function call isn't surround by a <script> tag.  You may want to try moving the function declaration above the function call.

Comment: @JasonNesbitt Sorry that was a typo while copying the code. Please see the update.

Comment: Put this part <script type="text/javascript">
function doStuff(A, B){...};
</script> inside the script manager tag.

Comment: This is a content page. The script manager is in the Master page. Thanks.

Comment: ok, write your script code in a js file and register it within the scriptManager in your masterpage.

Comment: @Bayeni Tried it. Still it doesn't work. Thanks.